# Sorted collection in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

My domain class is as follows:

```
package org.hibernate.auction.model;

import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.hibernate.auction.util.ReverseStringComparator;

public class Item {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private SortedMap<String,String> images = new TreeMap<String,String>(new ReverseStringComparator());
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public SortedMap<String,String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    public void setImages(SortedMap<String,String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public void addImage(String imageName,String fileName){
        images.put(imageName, fileName);

    }

}
```

The corresponding mapping file Item.hbm.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jan 14, 2012 10:34:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.hibernate.auction.model.Item" table="ITEM">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ITEM_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <map name="images" table="ITEM_IMAGE" sort="org.hibernate.auction.util.ReverseStringComparator">
            <key column="ITEM_ID"/>
            <map-key type="java.lang.String" column="IMAGENAME"></map-key>
            <element type="java.lang.String" column="FILENAME" not-null="true"/>        
         </map>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The comparator is as follows:

```
package org.hibernate.auction.util;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class ReverseStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String strA, String strB){
        // Compare strB to strA, rather than strA to strB.
        return strB.compareTo(strA);
    }

}
```

The configuration hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql123</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpwh_ch6_1_6</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/model/Item.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The java application to test is as follows:

```
package org.hibernate.auction.model;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import persistence.HibernateUtil;
    public class JpwhCh6_1_6Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Item item1 = new Item();
            item1.setName("Foo");
            item1.addImage("Image One", "fooimage1.jpg");
            item1.addImage("Image Two", "fooimage2.jpg");
            item1.addImage("Image Three", "fooimage3.jpg");
            System.out.println(item1.getImages());


            Item item2 = new Item();
            item2.setName("Bar");

            Item item3 = new Item();
            item3.setName("Baz");
            session.save(item1);
            session.save(item2);
            session.save(item3);
            tx.commit();

            session.close();
            HibernateUtil.shutdown();

        }

    }
```

HibernateUtil is like this:

```
package persistence;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
     private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      static {
        try {
           sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
      }

      public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
          // Alternatively, we could look up in JNDI here
          return sessionFactory;
      }

      public static void shutdown() {
          // Close caches and connection pools
          getSessionFactory().close();
      }

}
```

In the database it is stored like this:

```
ITEM_ID FILENAME    IMAGENAME
1   fooimage1.jpg   Image One
1   fooimage3.jpg   Image Three
1   fooimage2.jpg   Image Two
```

Obviously I expected it to be in the order Image Two, Image Three, Image One.
What I am missing. This is from "Java Persistence with Hibernate" book. I am using Hibernate 3.6.9 version.
I tried with all 3 sort options: unsorted,natural,class name of a comparator.They do not have any effect.

Comment: try implementing .equals and hashcode methods in your Item class..

Comment: why do u want how it is stored in database, while retrieving just sort it. Anyway database storage is not fixed.

Comment: @Ramesh, Yeah I agree with you.Should not bother about how it gets stored in database.Rather only concentrate on upon retrieval from database how it is held in persistent context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is that Hibernate replaces your TreeMap with its own Map implementation in order to implement cascading, lazy-loading, and so on, and that it's impossible for Hiberbate to know that the map must be sorted according to your comparator.

You thus need to tell Hibernate that your map should be sorted, and give it the class of the comparator to use. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e10663.

Note that since you provide a setter for this map and blindly replace the current map with the map passed as argument, anyone could replace the map with another one which is not sorted the same way. There shouldn't be a public setter for this property.

Comment: Now my understanding is: it is not possible to control the order in which entries will be stored in the database.Through mapping we can only control how the collection gets loaded in session.Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I don't really see how it relates to your original question, though.

Comment: @Nizet,I wrongly expected that I will be able to control how the domain object will be stored in the database.So I was passing comparator, removing it from the TreeMap & was expecting that it will affect the order of database storage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in your Comparator class. The compare method that you provided return a int value based on the comparison of the two strings (1 if strA > strB, 0 if strA == strB and -1 if strA < strB). that's why you get the rows sorted in an alphabetic order of the key (Image One, Image Three then Image Two). if you want a reversed result, say, (Image Two, Image Three then Image One), try to modify your comparator class as follows:

```
@Override
public int compare(String strA, String strB){
    if(strB.equals(strB) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -strB.compareTo(strA);
    }
}
```